# Passing settings to slick carousel directive in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to integrate [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in to my angular application. Slick already has a directive, so the only thing that I need to do in my html is this:

```
<slick>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">
        <img ng-src="{{item.image}}">
    </div>
</slick>
```

Okay, so it works. But now if I want to pass some settings to add them as attributes on the `<slick>` element

```
<slick infinite=true speed=300 slides-to-show=4 slides-to-scroll=4>
```

This also works, but I want to pass those settings from my angular app and not inside the `html` any suggestion of how doing this? Trying to pass the settings like this:

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.slickConfig = {
        "infinite": true,
        "speed": 300,
        "slides-to-show": 4,
        "slides-to-scroll": 4
    };
}])
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, slick] asking for new/isolated scope on: <slick ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm unfamiliar with slick, but according to their gitHub it's something like

```
$scope.slickConfig = {
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slides-to-show: 4,
        slides-to-scroll: 4
};
```

Update:
It seems like you need to add the config in the HTML like

```
<slick settings="slickConfig">
```

Comment: I updated a little the question. Anyway this gives me an error of `Unexpected token -` Because of the "-" in `slides-to-show`

Comment: I read the documentation in more detail and solved it. There are some things that the documentation does not mention so I answered my own question with all the code necessary to make it work. Including a correction, because in the documentation the route to the jQuery library is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could lead you on the right path

Answer (score 0):

In order to work correctly is necessary something like this in the app:

```
myAppModule.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.slickConfig = {
        autoplay: true,
        draggable: false,  
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        method: {},
        event: {
            beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            },
            afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            }
        }
    };  
}])
```

And something like this, in the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='MyApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Slider Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">

    <slick 
            settings="slickConfig"
            data="number">
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_01.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_02.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_03.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_04.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_05.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_06.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_07.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_08.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_09.jpg">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/img_10.jpg">
        </div>
    </slick>

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-slick-carousel/dist/angular-slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```